# Почему в цикле while компилятор находит ошибку, а в for - нет?

Tags: java, while, for

Это работает нормально:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
        sho += str.substring(i, i+1);
      }
```

Тут выходит за пределы (строка sho =...):

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= str.length()) {
    sho = sho + str.substring(i,i+1);
    i += 2;
  }
```

Comment: Продумайте тщательно свой цикл. Уверены ли вы, что при вызове метода `substring` второй параметр (`endIndex`) , который вычисляется как `i + 1`, никогда не может превышать длину строки?

Answer (score 5):

*Компилятор* не находит ошибку ни в  `for`, ни в `while`. Выполнятор - находит, потому что условия выполнения циклов отличаются.

```
while (i < str.length()) {
```